# Automatically increasing ID generation using PERL

Tags: perl

I'm stuck with the generation IDs for the XML elements if they were nor defined.
The case:
There are a couple XML documents with the same structure. I should find all the "table" elements and add to all of them the IDs like "section-table-XXXX" there "XXXX" - automatically generated number starting from 0001 and increasing for each "table" found.
The best way is to use Perl, but I don't know the Perl so much to use it.
Please help.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Keep a counter

```
$i = 0;
```

every time a table (either in a for or a while loop) is found do an incremental step and use it to declare the name of your table.

```
$i++; 
$table_name = "section-table-$i"
```

To get your 4 digit id, use sprintf. http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html

```
$i++; 
$table_id = sprintf<%04s> ,11;
$table_name = "section-table-$table_id";
```

note the double quote.

printf is used to print a string formatted by a given pattern
sprintf returns the printed string instead of print it out

sprintf and printf are really useful. You should check it out. (althought the perldoc is abit complex and messy)

%04s means return a string based on that is 4 character long and fill it with 0 as default.

another example :

```
perl -e '$x = "world"; $z=sprintf<"hello\t%s">, $x; print $z'
```

will print "hello\tworld"

Play around. its really useful. 
Let me know if you need more help

Cheers

Comment: This is not exactly what I search for. The ID number (XXXX) should be exactly four digits. So I need to count the tables found and if it lower than 10 - add three zeroes before it, if it greater than 10 but lower than 100 - add two eroes before, atc. Also I mean I need full code, because I really noob in Perl :) Thanks.

Comment: I tried to use XSLT to solve the problem, but I found that XSLT can't leave the initial file as is except the IDs for tables - it crashes the line wrap, delete the <!DOCTYPE> element and so on.

Comment: @protogenoff sprintf and printf to the rescue!